A question on Euler characteristic
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $D$ be a Cartier divisor on $X$. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$. I think the following equality of Euler characteristic is valid
$$
\chi(mD,\mathscr{F}|_{mD})=m\chi(D,\mathscr{F}|_D),
$$
where $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.
I don't know how to prove it seriously, but I think so cause by asymptotic Riemann-Roch theorem I can see the leading terms of the asymptotic expansions of them are the same. Could anyone give me some hints or counterexamples? Thanks in advance for any kind help!

Did you try to check an example?

This is not true. First, let us rewrite both sides of your equation. Consider the short exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(-mD) \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F|}_{mD} \rightarrow 0 $$
Because Euler characteristic is additive on short exact sequences, we have that
$$\chi(\mathcal{F|}_{mD}) = \chi(\mathcal{F}) - \chi(\mathcal{F}(-mD))$$
Now consider the case when $D$ is a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1)$.
Then $\chi(\mathcal{F|}_{D}) = \chi(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1)) - \chi(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-2)) = 0$
and $\chi(\mathcal{F|}_{2D}) = \chi(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-2)) - \chi(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-3)) = 1$
therefore $\chi(\mathcal{F|}_{2D}) \neq 2 \chi(\mathcal{F|}_{D})$.
